# JPA EntityManager blocks after @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, transactions

I have a Spring-JUnit test with a setup method that uses JPA Entities to setup test data. Within the test itself, legacy code uses JDBC-Templates to query the inserted test data. When the legacy code issues a query, the call to jdbcTemplate.query(...) hangs.

My Unit Test looks like this:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testContext.xml" })
@Transactional
public class MyTest {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "someUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // here some legacy Code is called that uses JDBC Templates to query 
        // the inserted test data. The legacy code hangs upon jdbcTemplate.query(...)
    }

    @Before 
    public void before() {
        this.entityManager.persist(new Entity1(...));
        this.entityManager.persist(new Entity2(...));
    }

}
```

My question is: Why doesn't the enitymanager commit upon exiting the before() method? Or does it commit and immediately start a new transaction, that still references the stored entity? I also tried to do without the junit annotation @Before annotation and manually call the before() method. But this gives the same result.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test class**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class MyTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "someUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private BeforeService beforeService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        beforeService.before();
        // here some legacy Code is called that uses JDBC Templates to query 
        // the inserted test data. The legacy code hangs upon jdbcTemplate.query(...)
    }

}
```

**Before Service**

```
public class BeforeService {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void before() {
        entityManager.persist(new Entity1(...));
        entityManager.persist(new Entity2(...));
    }
}
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: Thanks. Great. The Transaction annotations are only processed on service boundaries.

Comment: it was a pleasure to help you :)